# Soft links over the Web?

Tags: web-development, networking

Take this scenario. There is a server(say, A) at www.mysite.com .Now, there's a dynamic number of servers A knows about (knows the IP-adresses to).

The problem is, if a user arrives at http://www.mysite.com/B, we need to redirect him to the server that the URI B will map to( assume that there exists a mapping from such URLs to the list of known servers, and that 'B' is valid here). Is there a way of doing this without redirection? (First deployment will be n GAE, so this redirection is not possible). What I want is the browser showing http://www.mysite.com/B, but rendering content as delivered by the server running on B.

I think that this *may* be possible, as, multiple webservers are indeed used within the same domain today.

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation? Or are you looking for a way to configure GAE to help you out? This sounds like a question for either [SO] or [Webmasters.SE], to be honest.

Comment: Yes, maybe. actually I was doing the coding part, and the network guy leaves. The question is about configuration, but I'm not really sure whether this will require additional server side logic other than plain server config. So decided to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Load Balancing and Clustering](http://www.wellho.net/solutions/general-load-balancing-and-clustering.html) notes in part:

> With a simple LOAD BALANCING scheme, you can split your traffic down
>   by URL or subdirectory, so that (for example) all traffic for /course
>   goes to one server, and all traffic for /horse goes to another, with
>   the front end machine acting simply as a router, forwarding requests
>   via mod_proxy (if it's running Apache httpd) or similar.

Or does this not cover the case you are describing?

Comment: I accepted this as an answer as this was more (really speaking, many times more) elegant than what I had in mind (I am just the lazy programmer!!). Thank You JB King!!, Let me know what you think of http://rydyrect.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired behaviour by using a [forward proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Forward_proxies). It has nothing to do with programming.